# How to save emoji form when I transfer csv to txt in python

Tags: python, csv, txt

```
import csv
s = input("Your file name:")
with open(str(s), newline='', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    a = list(rows)
    print(a)
    with open('total.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for i in range(1, len(a)):
            if a[i][4] == "":
                if a[i][5] == "":
                    output_file.write(a[i][1]+":"+a[i][2]+"   ")
                else:
                    output_file.write(a[i][1]+":"+a[i][2] +
                                  " "+"小編:"+a[i][5]+"   ")
            else:
                if a[i][5] == "":
                    output_file.write("["+a[i][4]+"]"+" " +
                                  a[i][1]+":"+a[i][2]+"   ")
                else:
                    output_file.write("["+a[i][4]+"]"+" " +
                                  a[i][1]+":"+a[i][2]+" "+"小編:"+a[i][5]+"   ")
```

I am trying to transfer csv file to txt file. However, i can not handle the emoji problem that i want to remain emoji form.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you working on Windows or Linux? On Linux, this might work because the default encoding is usually utf-8, but typically not on Windows. Either way, try declaring `encoding="utf-8"` when you open `output_file`.

Comment: If that doesn't do it, then tell us more - show us a line of input, and the incorrect output you get from it. As Yevhen says, give us a reproducible example.